# Interface-EJB not injected in no-interface-EJB

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, ejb, jax-rs

**Awaiting answers.**

I've a JAX-RS controller (Jersey 2.21 on WildFly 9.0).

```
@Named
@Path("v1/populateList/")
public class PopulateDataController {

    @EJB
    ListItemService listItemService;

    @GET
    @Path("auto")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String populateList(){
        listItemService.populateList();
        return "done";
    }
}
```

The below `ListItemService` no-interface EJB is successfully injected in above JAX-RS controller.

```
@Stateless
public class ListItemService {

    @EJB
    ListItemDao listItemDao;

    public void populateList(){
        listItemDao.persist();
    }
}
```

However, the below `ListItemDaoImpl` interface-EJB is not in turn injected in above no-interface EJB.

```
@Stateless
public class ListItemDaoImpl implements ListItemDao{

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "pu")
    private EntityManager em;

    public void persist(){
        ListItem listItem = new ListItem();
        listItem.setLevel(1);
        listItem.setName("item1");
        em.persist(listItem);
    }
}
```

The `listItemDao` remains `null` in `populateList()` method of `ListItemService`, causing `NullPointerException`.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

**--- Edit and update ---**

I tried to make a Singleton bean to run on startup (to check my app logic).
It works fine without JAX RS. So its clear that the **problem is not with EJB but JAX RS.** (Do correct me if wrong)

```
    @Singleton
    @Startup
    public class TestController {
        @EJB
        ListItemService listItemService;

        @PostConstruct
        void test(){
        System.out.println("starting..........");
        listItemService.populateList();
        System.out.println("ending..........");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Did you annotate your 'ListItemDao' interface with @Local ?

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for fixing my question

Comment: @Szarpul yes. `@Local
public interface ListItemDao{
    void persist();
}`

Comment: @BalusC oh, I am not an expert. Just thought that the error trace might have some other information (like class names etc) or otherthings that I might not be aware of the importance and those might be useful for others.

Comment: Not in this case. A specific EJB not being injected is sufficient clue. Keep your question as focused as possible. You're not interested in why a `NullPointerException` is thrown. You're interested in why the EJB not is injected.

Comment: oh ok. I will remove the error

Comment: On GlassFish 4, your code works fine. I suspect this is an issue with WildFly

Comment: @perissf Did you tried it on wildfly? and you dont have other envirnment like web.xml etc. Can you paste the full project that worked for you in glassfish?

Comment: I have not tried on wildfly. On GlassFish I have used web.xml for registering the RESTful web service as explained in any "Hello World" jax-rs tutorial. Note that I have omitted the injection of the PersistenceContext because it's not relevant to the problem.

Comment: @perissf would definitly need it to work on wildfly and with environment xml or other relevant things. It also seems a known problem if you google

Comment: Tested on WildFly 10.0.0.CR2. Works fine without issues. I suspect there are other issues in your code that you haven't mentioned. Maybe you have used some imports from wrong packages? Is this a true MCVE? See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @perissf in that case, here is the full package I have http://52.10.84.132/goo.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating the following class helped.

```
    @javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("api")
    public class InjectionApplication extends javax.ws.rs.core.Application {
        private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
        private Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

        public InjectionApplication() {
        // no instance is created, just class is listed
        classes.add(ListItemController.class); //replace with yours
        classes.add(ParseFeedController.class); //replace with yours
        //add more or use some auto class finding technique

        }

        @Override
        public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return classes;
        }

        @Override
        public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return singletons;
        }
    }
```